# Carto - problem with data import in carto format

Tags: carto, import

I want to do some CARTO guides (https://carto.com/learn/guides) but I can't import the data. It is already a carto format and it doesn't work when I try to drag&drop the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you dropping the carto file into your maps dashboard (instead of datasets)? Are you getting an error? If so, please send that to CARTO support (support@carto.com).

Comment: I choose New datasets in the right corner --> Data file --> Drag&drop your file I choose the file (templete_add points for Dominos Stores.carto) --> Connect Dataset. I get the green message just with the name of the file, but it doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: As far I understand, what you are trying to import a dataset that is inside a CARTO file. Have you tried to import the whole CARTO file into the maps dashboard directly?

Comment: Yes, when I try to import the all zip file I get this mistake: Unsupported/Unrecognized file type (1002)

Comment: Could you send your inquiry to support@carto.com adding your username or the error code associated to that message?